# abort() was called at PC 0x400e1e36 on core 1 in ESP32

Tags: arduino, esp32, abort

I am working on a project called sound box. It will give audio feedback regarding the amount received. Here I am using

1. ESP32 Dev Board
2. SIM800L GSM Module with a 2G SIM card
3. DF Player mini

It's working fine but the issue is that each time after the audio feedback esp32 getting reset
showing error

```
abort() was called at PC 0x400e1e32 on core 0

Backtrace:0x40083699:0x3ffb26100x4008835d:0x3ffb2630 0x4008cfa5:0x3ffb2650 0x400e1e32:0x3ffb26d0 0x400d15ca:0x3ffb2770 0x400d1ece:0x3ffb27c0 0x400d2094:0x3ffb2800 0x400d3e9d:0x3ffb2820
```

code:

```
// Please select the corresponding model

// #define SIM800L_IP5306_VERSION_20190610
#define SIM800L_AXP192_VERSION_20200327
// #define SIM800C_AXP192_VERSION_20200609
// #define SIM800L_IP5306_VERSION_20200811

// Set serial for debug console (to the Serial Monitor, default speed 115200)
#define SerialMon Serial

// Define the serial console for debug prints, if needed
#define DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#define TINY_GSM_DEBUG          SerialMon
#include<string.h>

// Configure TinyGSM library
#define TINY_GSM_MODEM_SIM800          // Modem is SIM800
#define TINY_GSM_RX_BUFFER      1024   // Set RX buffer to 1Kb
#include <TinyGsmClient.h>

//library for df_mini_player
#include "Arduino.h"
#include "SoftwareSerial.h"
#include "DFRobotDFPlayerMini.h"

// Set serial for AT commands (to the module)
#define SerialAT  Serial2
  
#ifdef DUMP_AT_COMMANDS
#include <StreamDebugger.h>
StreamDebugger debugger(SerialAT, SerialMon);
TinyGsm modem(debugger);
#else
TinyGsm modem(SerialAT);
#endif


char* msg = "+cmt: \"+919988774455\"";

//setting all required global variables.
char* lower = "";
char* response = "";
String res = "";

String final_amount = "";
int Prev_button = 26;

//added for df_mini_updated.
DFRobotDFPlayerMini myDFPlayer;
void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value);
SoftwareSerial mySoftwareSerial(33, 25); // RX, TX

void setup()
{
  pinMode(21, OUTPUT);//led high after network connection.
  digitalWrite(21, LOW);
  
  pinMode(26,INPUT);//previous button..
  
  // Set console baud rate
  SerialMon.begin(9600);
  SerialAT.begin(9600);
  mySoftwareSerial.begin(9600); 
  delay(100);

  if (!myDFPlayer.begin(mySoftwareSerial,true,false)) {  //Use mySoftwareSerial to communicate with mp3.
    Serial.println(F("Unable to begin:"));
    Serial.println(F("1.Please recheck the connection!"));
    Serial.println(F("2.Please insert the SD card!"));
    while (true);
  }

  //initializing df_mini_player.
  Serial.println();
  Serial.println(F("DFRobot DFPlayer Mini Demo"));
  Serial.println(F("Initializing DFPlayer ... (May take 3~5 seconds)"));
  Serial.println(F("DFPlayer Mini online."));
  myDFPlayer.volume(25);  //Set volume value. From 0 to 30 

  //  power on command.
  myDFPlayer.play(1);
  delay(4000);
      
  SerialMon.println("Initializing modem...");SerialMon.println("Waiting for network...");
      
  if (!modem.waitForNetwork(600000L, true)) {
    delay(10000);
    return;
  }

  if (modem.isNetworkConnected())
  {
    digitalWrite(21, HIGH);
    delay(1500);
    myDFPlayer.play(2);// Network connected voice command.
    delay(1500);

    SerialMon.println("Network connected");
  }
  SerialAT.println("AT"); //Once the handshake test is successful, it will back to OK
  updateSerial();
  SerialAT.println("AT+CMGF=1"); // Configuring TEXT mode
  updateSerial();
  SerialAT.println("AT+CNMI=1,2,0,0,0"); // Decides how newly arrived SMS messages should be handled
  
}
void loop()
{
  if (myDFPlayer.available())
  {
    printDetail(myDFPlayer.readType(), myDFPlayer.read()); //Print the detail message from DFPlayer to handle different errors and states.
  }
  updateSerial();
}

void updateSerial()
{
  int x = 0;
  delay(500);
  while (!SerialAT.available())
  {
    // repeat last amount.
    if (digitalRead(Prev_button) == LOW)
      voice_commands(final_amount);
    delay(100);
  }
  
  // res stores the entire message 
  while (SerialAT.available())
  {
    char add = SerialAT.read();
    res = res + add;
    delay(1);
  }

  if (1) {
    response = &res[0];
    //------------------------------------------------- Converting every character of the String in lower form
    const int length = strlen( response ); // get the length of the text
    lower = ( char* )malloc( length + 1 ); // allocate 'length' bytes + 1 (for null terminator) and cast to char*
    lower[ length ] = 0; // set the last byte to a null terminator
    //------------------------------------------------- copy all character bytes to the new buffer using tolower
    for ( int i = 0; i < length; i++ )
    {
      lower[ i ] = tolower( response[ i ] );
    }
    Serial.print("whole Msg - "); Serial.println(lower);
    Serial.println("\n");

// check for rs || rs. and paytm QR code registered mobile number.
    if (strstr(lower, "rs") &&  strstr(lower, "+919988774455")) {
      //Serial.print("Our Msg - "); Serial.println(lower);
      CheckWordInString_rs(lower);
    }

    if (strstr(lower, "rs.") && strstr(lower, "++919988774455")) {
      CheckWordInString_rsDot(lower);
    }
    response = "";
    res = "";
    lower = "";

  }
}


int CheckWordInString_rs(char source[100]) {

 // Serial.print("Source message - "); Serial.println(source);

  if (1) {

    int i = 0, s = 0;
    
    while (lower[i] != 'r' || lower[i + 1] != 's')i++; //checks the position of rs and stores the position of r in variable i.

    //string slicing form i+3 position.
    String result = (String)lower;
    result = result.substring(i + 3);
    Serial.print("Substring - "); Serial.println(result);
    
    i = 0;// loop stores the position of first space in substring.
    while (result[i] != ' ' )i++;
    delay(100);
    
    // string slicing to store final_amount
    final_amount = result.substring(0, i);
    Serial.print("Final Amount - "); Serial.println(final_amount);
  
    voice_commands(final_amount); //Voice function called.
  }
}

int CheckWordInString_rsDot(char source[100]) {

 // Serial.print("Source Message - "); Serial.println(source);

  if (1) {

    int i = 0, s = 0;
    while (lower[i] != 'r' || lower[i + 1] != 's' || lower[i + 2] != '.')i++;
    delay(100);

    String result = (String)lower;
    result = result.substring(i + 4);
    Serial.print("Second");
    Serial.print("Substring -"); Serial.println(result);

    i = 0;
    while (result[i] != ' ' )i++;
          
    String   final_amount = result.substring(0, i);
    Serial.print("Final Amount - "); Serial.println(final_amount);

    voice_commands(final_amount);

  }
  return 1;
}

void voice_commands(String amount) {

  const char * float_amount = amount.c_str();
  int amount_int = amount.toInt();
  String amt_conversion = (String)amount_int;
  int amount_len = amt_conversion.length();
  Serial.println("amount_int");
  Serial.println(amount_int);

  if (amount_int !=0){
  delay(2000);  
  myDFPlayer.play(3); // Amount Received Voice note
  delay(1500);
  myDFPlayer.play(6);
  delay(1500);
  }
  if(amount_int == 0){
  delay(2000);  
  myDFPlayer.play(3); // Amount Received Voice note
  delay(1500);
  }
//if amount is less than and equal to 20.
  if (amount_int <= 280) {

    myDFPlayer.playMp3Folder(amount_int); //play specific mp3 in SD:/MP3/amount_int.mp3; File Name(0~65535)
    delay(1500);
    Serial.println(amount_int);
  }


  //loop to extract decimal value from amount...
  if(strstr(float_amount, ".")){
     
    int i=0;
    while(amount[i] != '.')i++;

       String sliced_amount = amount.substring(i+1);
       int decimal_value = sliced_amount.toInt();
       String amt_conversion = (String)decimal_value;
       int decimal_len = amt_conversion.length();
       

     Serial.println(decimal_len);
     Serial.println(decimal_value);

       // voice command for (and) is stored at 65000..
       if(amount_int != 0){
        myDFPlayer.play(5);
        delay(1500);
       }
     
      if(decimal_value <= 280){

        myDFPlayer.playMp3Folder(decimal_value);
        delay(1500);
        Serial.println(decimal_value);
        }
      }
        // voice command for paise is stored at 64000..
        myDFPlayer.play(4);
        delay(1500);


//    //end command placed at 61000.
//    myDFPlayer.playMp3Folder(61000); //play specific mp3 in SD:/MP3/amount_int.mp3; File Name(0~65535)
//    delay(2000);
}


void printDetail(uint8_t type, int value)//function to handle different errors of df_mini_player
{
  switch (type) {
    case TimeOut:
      Serial.println(F("Time Out!"));
      break;
    case WrongStack:
      Serial.println(F("Stack Wrong!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardInserted:
      Serial.println(F("Card Inserted!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardRemoved:
      Serial.println(F("Card Removed!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerCardOnline:
      Serial.println(F("Card Online!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerPlayFinished:
      Serial.print(F("Number:"));
      Serial.print(value);
      Serial.println(F(" Play Finished!"));
      break;
    case DFPlayerError:
      Serial.print(F("DFPlayerError:"));
      switch (value) {
        case Busy:
          Serial.println(F("Card not found"));
          break;
        case Sleeping:
          Serial.println(F("Sleeping"));
          break;
        case SerialWrongStack:
          Serial.println(F("Get Wrong Stack"));
          break;
        case CheckSumNotMatch:
          Serial.println(F("Check Sum Not Match"));
          break;
        case FileIndexOut:
          Serial.println(F("File Index Out of Bound"));
          break;
        case FileMismatch:
          Serial.println(F("Cannot Find File"));
          break;
        case Advertise:
          Serial.println(F("In Advertise"));
          break;
        default:
          break;
      }
      break;
    default:
      break;
  }
}
```

Comment: Use https://github.com/me-no-dev/EspExceptionDecoder to get a stack position for your crash. Otherwise it's like looking for a needle in a haystack.

Answer (score 0):

You can turn

```
Backtrace:0x40083699:0x3ffb26100x4008835d:0x3ffb2630 0x4008cfa5:0x3ffb2650 0x400e1e32:0x3ffb26d0 0x400d15ca:0x3ffb2770 0x400d1ece:0x3ffb27c0 0x400d2094:0x3ffb2800 0x400d3e9d:0x3ffb2820
```

into the specific code line with the espressif's `xtensa-esp32-elf-addr2line`

That could give you a better idea about the problem you are trying to solve.
More information [here](https://esp32.com/viewtopic.php?t=23384)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).